# How do I template a member variable without templating the class?

Tags: c++

I have an untemplated class called Food. Inside Food, there is a vector of Apple pointers. Apple is a class also inside Food. Class Apple has two vectors that point to another class and a comparator. I will not know until runtime what type of comparators they will be.

I need the comparator to be templated. Both may have different comparators, which is why I can't template apple. If I template apple then Food's vector of Apple pointers will get disrupted because there may be 2 comparators.

I guess I could template apple with 2 separate comparators, but I feel there is a more elegant way. Also what if I want to change the comparators midprogram at some point, which is why that won't work either.

Is it possible to template the comparators without templating apple? or is there another solution

```
class Food {
class Apple {
    vector<Pointer, Comparator> container_one;
    vector<Pointer, Comparator> container_two;
}

vector<Apple *> appleContainer
};
```

Comment: What kind of vector is it? `std::vector` doesn't have a `Comparator` template parameter.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. Things that can't be coded normally shows a reality to design problem.

Comment: @Klaus _Normally_ here could mean "within the confines of the language's deficiencies." If we always called that a design problem, the language would never get anywhere.

Comment: You need to "assign" the comparator to your Apple class in some way. Maybe you can show us how you would like to "assign" the comparator and we can get a better idea about what you want. And to change it in run-time, there are quite a few options here: A) lambda B) functors C) custom defined comparator class...

Answer (score 2):

Template parameters need to be resolved at compile-time, so there is no way to have a "unresolved" template-member inside a non-template class.

It looks like what you need is inheritance instead of templates. Make a class `Comparator` and different child-classes like `ComparatorA`, `ComparatorB`.
Then store two objects of type `Comparator*` in your apple, one for each vector (or one in each vector). Whether you assign an object of base-class or child-classes doesn't matter here, you can use both - and using virtual functions the proper function can be resolved at runtime.